# Standalone Package: Convert multiple tikzpictures to png

Tags: standalone, png

I want to export multiple tikzpictures as png, directly within latex with the help of imagemagick. I use texifier on mac. The current code does only work for one picture, the rest of the pictures are not exported. I use a modified standaloneconfig file:

```
\standaloneconfig{
  multi=tikzpicture,
  crop=true,
  convert={
    density=300,
    convertexe=convert,
    outext=.png,
    command={%
      \convertexe\space
      -density 300\space 
      \infile\space
      -quality 90\space 
      \outfile
    }
  }
}
```

The latex code it self looks like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define high-contrast colors
    \definecolor{brightyellow}{rgb}{1, 1, 0.6} % Bright yellow
    \definecolor{brightcyan}{rgb}{0.6, 1, 1} % Bright cyan
    \definecolor{brightmagenta}{rgb}{1, 0.6, 1} % Bright magenta

    % First ellipse
    \def\firstellipse{(-4,0) ellipse (8 and 3)}
    % Fill the first ellipse with bright yellow
    \fill[brightyellow] \firstellipse;
    % Draw the outline of the first ellipse with wider line
    \draw[line width=2pt] \firstellipse;
    % Label for the first ellipse
    \node[draw=none] at (-10,0) {\Huge $A$};
    
    \draw[line width=2pt] (-15,-8) rectangle ++(30,16);
    \node[draw=none] at (-14,7) {\Huge $\Omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define high-contrast colors
    \definecolor{brightyellow}{rgb}{1, 1, 0.6} % Bright yellow
    \definecolor{brightcyan}{rgb}{0.6, 1, 1} % Bright cyan
    \definecolor{brightmagenta}{rgb}{1, 0.6, 1} % Bright magenta

    % Second ellipse
    \def\secondellipse{(4,0) ellipse (8 and 3)}
    % Fill the second ellipse with bright cyan
    \fill[brightcyan] \secondellipse;
    % Draw the outline of the second ellipse with wider line
    \draw[line width=2pt] \secondellipse;
    % Label for the second ellipse
    \node[draw=none] at (10,0) {\Huge $B$};

    % Optional: Draw a surrounding rectangle
    \draw[line width=2pt] (-15,-8) rectangle ++(30,16);
    \node[draw=none] at (-14,7) {\Huge $\Omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the standalone.cfg file or the latex file, such that I get multiple

Comment: With your example and your `standalone.cfg`, `pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex` results in `test-0.png` and `test-1.png`. I'm using an up-to-date TeX Live 2023 and Linux. The internal convert run reported in the `log` file is: `convert -density 300 test.pdf -quality 90 test-%01d.png`. `standalone` only reports `Output written on test-1.png`, nevertheless, `test-0.png` is also generated.

Comment: When I convert PDFs to PNGs (using Acrobat), each page gets a different file.  LaTeX doesn't support multiple output files.

Comment: I get this error: ```runsystem(convert -density 300 "Conditional Probablity".pdf -transparent white "Conditional Probablity"-%01d.png)...executed.

Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!```
But when I run ```convert -density 300 "Conditional Probablity".pdf -transparent white "Conditional Probablity"-%01d.png```in terminal, the conversion does work. So I tried to add full disk access to texifier, but nothing changes.